# Pairing table query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, many-to-many, erd

I was wondering how I construct a query to get all articles with all their information, and for every article a list with their tags. I used a pairing table called ArticleTags to connect Article and Tags.

Can anyone tell me what the query would be if I wanted to receive all articles along with their tags per article.

My ERD:
[image: ERD of database]

I am using the Node module 'mysql'.

Comment: you need a INNER JOIN statement

Comment: Yeah i figured, but in what order..

Comment: If you use JOIN you'll need an expensive `GROUP BY` to suppress duplicates.

Comment: Please provide desired output example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```sql
SELECT article.*, (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tag.name ORDER BY tag.name SEPARATOR ', ')
    FROM articletag
    JOIN tag ON articletag.tagId = tag.id
    WHERE articletag.articleId = article.id
) AS tag_list
FROM article
```

Answer (score 0):

This is textbook join case:

```
select *
from ArticleTag as atag
join Article as a on atag.articleid = a.id
join Tag as t on atag.tagid = t.id
```

Please read some textbook on SQL.